# How do I create a new feature class from an existing FC and a WHERE clause?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, error-000800

I have a feature class. I want to copy the FC and use a WHERE clause to limit the rows copied. I tried using the CopyFeatures_management but it throws an error on the `CopyFeatures_management()` line.

Here's the code:

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = 'C:/.../localFile.gdb'

inFC = 'inputFeatureClassName'
outFC = 'tmp_JUNK'

arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(inFC, outFC, '"FIELD_NAME" = "VALUE"')
```

The error thrown:

```
arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000800: The value is not a member of  | DEFAULTS | TEXT_UTF16 | MAX_FILE_SIZE_4GB | MAX_FILE_SIZE_256TB | GEOMETRY_OUTOFLINE | BLOB_OUTOFLINE | GEOMETRY_AND_BLOB_OUTOFLINE | TERRAIN_DEFAULTS | MOSAICDATASET_DEFAULTS | MOSAICDATASET_INLINE.
Failed to execute (CopyFeatures).
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it?

Update #1 - This code works but I question whether it's really the best approach. If I understand this, I create a feature layer, perform the selection on the feature layer, and then write the selection to a new feature class. Is that correct? Is this the most efficient approach?

```
    # Import system modules
    import arcpy
    from arcpy import env

    # Set overwrite option
    arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

    # Put in error trapping in case an error occurs when running tool
    try:

       # Make a layer from the feature class
       arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("C:/.../localFile.gdb/tmp_FeatureClass","tmpOMG")

       arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("tmpOMG", "NEW_SELECTION", """"FIELD_NAME" = 'VALUE'""")

       # Write the selected features to a new featureclass
       arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("tmpOMG", "C:/.../localFile.gdb/tmpOutFromLayer")

except:
   print arcpy.GetMessages()
```

source: [ArcGIS Help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000006p000000)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use a `where_clause` with Copy Features. [Looking at the help page](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000035000000), the syntax is (with optional parameters in `{}` brackets):

> CopyFeatures_management (in_features, out_feature_class, {config_keyword}, {spatial_grid_1}, {spatial_grid_2}, {spatial_grid_3})

So you're passing `'"FIELD_NAME" = "VALUE"'` as a config_keyword, which is confusing it and causing the error. You can only limit the features copied by starting off with a selection, and selections can only happen on layers (as in your second snippet).

---

I generally use [Feature Class to Feature Class](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001200000020000000) (`arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion`), which *can* accept a where_clause.

> FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion (in_features, out_path, out_name, **{where_clause}**, {field_mapping}, {config_keyword})

It's slightly annoying since you have to specify both output workspace and output feature class name, and I don't know why that's the case, but there you go. It's faster than `Select_analysis` (which does the same operation). For your case, the code would be something like:

```
arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(inFC, outGDB, outFC, '"FIELD_NAME" = "VALUE"')
```

Comment: I'm surprised that you say "faster than Select_analysis" - have you any timings to confirm that?

Comment: There was one particular subset-copy I needed to do on some very large (~500k features) dataset. `FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion` took 195.85 seconds, `Select_analysis` took 55738.53 seconds (15.5 hours). I haven't done _rigorous_ testing, although it would be interesting and informative to do so someday; this is extremely anecdotal on my part :)

Comment: What were the input and output formats?

Comment: FWIW, 4 seconds using select_analysis and 10 seconds using FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion. Starting with 20k records, filtering down to 1500. I like the "one line of code" solution but now I need to deal with those field mappings.

Comment: Going from SDE to a file GDB, feature class was points. The selection clause was the same for each. I can look for the test script and we can take this to a new Question, but I doubt it's still on my machine (I just kept the results in a snippets file I maintain for myself as a general set of reminders).

Comment: @DenaliHardtail Field mapping is optional (although useful once you get it working).

Comment: Really??? How? I have a question open to find that answer. http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/134571/how-do-i-omit-the-field-mapping-in-a-copy-as-python-snippet

Comment: Field mapping is optional _for some tools_, including FeatureClassToFeatureClass. Since _in this case_ you are making a new feature class, it won't cause an error to leave out field mapping (it'll just copy all the attributes).